# Check the following functions for injectivity and surjectivity

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**a)** $f: \mathbb{Q}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}, f(x)=x^2$

**b)** $g: \mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}, g(x)=\begin{cases}-\frac{x}{2} &\text{if x is even}\\\frac{x-1}{2}&\text{if x is not even}\end{cases}$

**c)** Let $M$ be the set of all humans, $V\subset M$ the set of all fathers and $h: M\rightarrow V$ be the function which associates each human to their biological father.

Bonus question:

**d)** One can also associate each human to their siblings, does this define a function $i: M\rightarrow M$?

---

---

Please examine my attempts at solving these exercises.

**a)** This function is neither injective nor surjective.

It is not injective since $f(-x)=x^2$ and $f(x)=x^2$ and as such $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\not\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$. For example $f(-2) = f(2) = 4$.

It is not surjective since no $x\in X$ exists for $f(x)<0$, for example $f(x)\neq 4$ for any $x\in X$, since $f^{-1}(-4)=\sqrt(-4)=\emptyset$ in $\mathbb{Q}$.

**b)** This function is bijective. This is my attempt.

Injectivity:

Case 1, $g(x)=-\frac{x}{2}$.

$-\frac{x_1}{2}=-\frac{x_2}{2} \Leftrightarrow -x_1=-x_2 \Leftrightarrow x_1=x_2$.

Case 2, $g(x)=\frac{x-1}{2}$.

$\frac{x_1-1}{2}=\frac{x_2-1}{2} \Leftrightarrow x_1-1=x_2-1 \Leftrightarrow x_1=x_2$.

Surjectivity:

Case 1. $-\frac{x}{2} = y \Leftrightarrow x=-2y$.

Case 2. $\frac{x-1}{2}=y \Leftrightarrow x=2y+1$.

Is this sufficient or even the correct approach?

**c)** This function is not injective, but surjective.

It is not injective because at least one father exists who has multiple children and as such for $f(x_1)=f(x_2)\not\Rightarrow x_1=x_2$ with $x_1$ being the sibling of $x_2$.

It is surjective because it follows from the definition of being a father that any father in $V$ must have at least one child in $M$.

**d)** No, it would not define a function, since not every person has a sibling they can be associated to. And as such there is no $f(x)$ for some $x\in M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your complete answers are completely correct and well put. For (b), you do not need induction. Injectivity can be shown in two cases. Assume $f(x)=f(y)$. Since $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ both have the same sign, $x$ and $y$ are either both even or both odd. In either case, you can substitute the appropriate formula for $f$ and proceed to prove $x=y$. To prove surjectivity, given $y\in \mathbb Z$, you must find $x$ so $f(x)=y$. Again, break into two cases based on the sign of $y$ to determine which form of $f$ to use.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response! I updated my post with an attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Someone has given you hints how to go about (b), so I will only make comments on (a), which can be made clearer:

First, where did you get the set $X$ from; what do you mean by it?

Also, you can simply provide a counterexample each. To show that the function is not injective, it suffices to show some positive rational number with two different pre-images ($4$ is the image of both $-2$ and $2$, e.g.). To show it is not surjective, simply find a rational that has no pre-image (any negative integer will do, e.g. $-4$).

Aside these I've not found other problems.

Comment: I meant to write $\mathbb{Q}$. Thank you!